# C# regex doesn't work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, backslash, xregexp

I am using the following regex to validate an email:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9!$'*+/\-_#%?^`&=~}{|]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9!$'*+/\-_#%?^`&=~}{|]+)*@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-['&_\]]]+)(\.[\w-['&_\]]]+)*))(\]?)$
```

This works fine in C# but in JavaScript, its not working.... and yes I replaced every backslash with a double backslash as the following:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9!$'*+/\\-_#%?^`&=~}{|]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!$'*+/\\-_#%?^`&=~}{|]+)*@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([\\w-['&_\\]]]+)(\\.[\\w-['&_\\]]]+)*))(\\]?)$
```

I am using XRegExp. Am I missing something here? Is there such thing as a converter to convert normal regex to JavaScript perhaps :) ?

Here is my function:

```
 function CheckEmailAddress(email) {
     var reg = new XRegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9!$'*+/\\-_#%?^`&=~}{|]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!$'*+/\\-_#%?^`&=~}{|]+)*@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([\\w-['&_\\]]]+)(\\.[\\w-['&_\\]]]+)*))(\\]?)$")

     if (reg.test(email) == false) {
         return false;
     }

     return true;
 }
```

It is returning false for a simple "abc@123.com" email address.

Thanks in advance!

Kevin

Comment: escaping a backslash means you're matching a literal `\`... JS regex's are pretty similar to PCRE's regex, but slightly _easier_. You shouldn't validate email addresses using regex. It can't be done... no one ever managed to validate _all_ valid email addresses using a single regex... Oh, and why are you using XRegExp, and not the simple regex?

Comment: How else do you reckon I validate an email format on the client's side?

Comment: You don't. You _can_ do some basic validation (like: does the input contain a `@` sign), but data validation is done _server-side_

Comment: No I cannot afford an invalid email format... so... back to my question. What is wrong with my regex?

Comment: Why not? aren't you performing _any_ server-side validation? Because _that_ is something you can't afford... not validating user-input server-side

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem XRegExp is required because the regular expression contains [character class subtractions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CharacterClassSubtraction). These are not supported by RegExp. And while regular expression are not the final answer as to the validity of an email address they can be part of a validation solution.

Comment: Actually, XRegExp does not support subtractions either. I forgot about that. So while it is true that RegExp does not support subtractions. XRegExp won't be the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your regular expression contains [character class subtractions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CharacterClassSubtraction). JavaScript's `RegExp` does not support them, nor does `XRegExp`. (I initially misremembered and commented that it does, but it does not.)

However, character class subtractions can be replaced with negative lookaheads so this:

```
[\w-['&_\\]]]
```

can become this:

```
(?:(?!['&_\\]])\\w)
```

Both mean "any word character but not one in the set `'&_]`". The expression `\w` does not match `'`, `&` or `]` so we can simplify to:

```
(?:(?!_)\\w)
```

Or since `\w` is `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, we can just remove the underscore from the list and further simplify to:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]
```

So the final RegExp is this:

```
new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9!$'*+/\\-_#%?^`&=~}{|]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!$'*+/\\-_#%?^`&=~}{|]+)*@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([A-Za-z0-9]+)(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*))(\\]?)$")
```

I've done modest testing with this RegExp, but you should do due diligence on checking it.

It is not strictly necessary to go through the negative lookahead step to simplify the regular expression but knowing that character class subtractions can be replaced with negative lookaheads is useful in more general cases where manual simplification would be difficult or brittle.

Comment: Wow, what a nice answer. How long have you been looking at regular expressions?

Comment: I've used regular expressions for years.

Comment: I use regex also for a long time, but I have never used this feature by myself. I heard about, but I failed to see this seldom construct here in this question. +1.